# Unmet dependencies / held packages for new package

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I'm trying to install a media server on my Raspberry Pi but it says I have unmet dependencies:

```
pi@pihole:~ $ sudo apt-get install ampache
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ampache : Depends: ampache-common (>= 3.6-rzb2704+dfsg-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try and install the above mentioned application:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ampache-common : Depends: libphp-phpmailer (< 5.2.14+dfsg.0~) but 6.0.6-0.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: php-getid3 (< 1.9.12+dfsg.0~) but 1.9.17+dfsg-1 is to be installed
                  Depends: php-gettext (< 1.0.11.0~) but 1.0.12-0.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The strange thing is, the versions it wants to install are already installed? Or is this telling me the above three apps are all too new? Any advice would be appreciated.

```
pi@pihole:~ $ sudo apt-get install php-gettext
php-gettext is already the newest version (1.0.12-0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
pi@pihole:~ $ sudo apt-get install php-getid3
php-getid3 is already the newest version (1.9.17+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Outputs:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi 
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
# deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi  

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main 
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
# deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main  

$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
raspi.list
```

Comment: Cross posting is not a good practice, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911597/raspberry-pi-unmet-dependencies-held-packages-for-ampache

Comment: @MatsKarlsson Sorry I thought they were separate parts of the site but I guess not, thanks.

Comment: I use exactly the same repositories, listed in `.. sources.list`, `.. raspi.list`. But when I do: `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt-get install ampache`, I get: `E: Unable to locate package ampache`. Why do you get it? Have you done `sudo apt update`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the packages you have on the Pi already or to load are too new.
Looking at the text you posted:

The package you need:

> ampache-common

Requires libphp-phpmailer to be earlier than 5.2.14 but you are about to install 6.0.6

> Depends: libphp-phpmailer (< 5.2.14+dfsg.0~) but 6.0.6-0.1 is to be installed

As for the:

> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

you could try:

```
sudo dkpg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

and see if that sorts out the errors.